# mod_remoteip not showing true IP of the visitor

Tags: apache-http-server, ip, php, cloudflare

I am trying to get the real IP behind Cloudflare.

I did as I found on Google, installed `mod_remoteip` then configure it as following:

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.21.244.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.22.200.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.31.4.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 104.16.0.0/13
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 104.24.0.0/14
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 108.162.192.0/18
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 131.0.72.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 141.101.64.0/18
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 162.158.0.0/15
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 172.64.0.0/13
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 173.245.48.0/20
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 188.114.96.0/20
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 190.93.240.0/20
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 197.234.240.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 198.41.128.0/17
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2400:cb00::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2606:4700::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2803:f800::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2405:b500::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2405:8100::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2a06:98c0::/29
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2c0f:f248::/32
```

When I check `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']` the IP is not my real IP, and there is not `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` set in the `$_SERVER`, what to do?

I added the list of IPs I found on Cloudflare list as `RemoteIPTrustedProxy` but that doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Whats the point of getting the IP address ?